# Prove that a linear map for complex polynomials is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question:**
Let $V=\Bbb C_n[X]$ be a vector space of polynomials of a degree $\le n$.
Let a map: $T:V \to V$ be $(T(p))(x)=p'(x)+p(0)x^n$
Prove that this map is diagonalizeable.

**What we did**
We tried reducing the problem to a vector space of dimension 2, and then transformed the map into a matrix, then doing the algorithm it may be possible to diagonalize it. But how do we generalize that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing down the matrix of $T$ w.r.t the basis $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n\}$?

Comment: How could you reduce this to bidimensional case? The dimension of $\;V\;$ is $\;n+1\;$ ...

Comment: Follow Prahlad's hint.  From that it's easy to compute the eigenvalues.  Show that there a $n+1$ pairwise different ones.  Why are you done then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}T(1)&=x^n\\
Tx&=1\\
Tx^2&=2x\\
\ldots&\ldots\\
Tx^n&=nx^{n-1}\end{align*}\implies \left[T\right]=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&\ldots&0&1\\
1&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&2&0&\ldots&0&0\\
\ldots\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&n&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus the characteristic polynomial is (if you want to formalize the following use a little induction).

$$\det(xI-[T])=\begin{vmatrix}x&0&0&\ldots&0&-1\\
-1&x&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&-2&x&\ldots&0&0\\
\ldots\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&-n&x\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$x\begin{vmatrix}x&0&0&\ldots&0&0\\
-2&x&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&-2&x&\ldots&0&0\\
\ldots\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&-n&x\end{vmatrix}+\begin{vmatrix}0&0&0&\ldots&0&-1\\
-2&x&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&-3&x&\ldots&0&0\\
\ldots\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&-n&x\end{vmatrix}=$$

$$=x(x^n)+(-1)^n\begin{vmatrix}-2&x&0&\ldots&0&0\\
0&-3&x&\ldots&0&0\\
0&0&-4&\ldots&0&0\\
\ldots\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
0&0&\ldots&0&0&-n\end{vmatrix}=x^{n+1}+(-1)^n(-1)^nn!=x^{n+1}+n!$$

Then all the eigenvalues of the matrix are different (why?!) and thus it is diagonalizable